# Method to Get Values from Multiple Textboxes with Same Tag Name Property?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

What command was it in C# where you could get the values of, let's say, multiple textboxes sharing the same name property in a form on post?

If i remember correctly, the value would be returned as an array.

> Edit:
>
> It was Request.Forms.GetValues
>
> Sorry for the trouble guys. >.<

Comment: You can't have text boxes with the same ID...

Comment: you can only have the same class, not the same id. Id is unique, class you can group.

Comment: Sorry, wrong question presentation (plus missing tag). I've updated my question, hope my question is clearer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only array supported for a TextBox in C# is using the Lines property in case of a multiline TextBox. There's nothing like a control array of VB. You can of course write your own wrapper of some kind.

Comment: Updated with answer. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be thinking of the control arrays we had in VB6 where the event handler received the index to the control in the array. No such thing in c#.

Comment: Actually I used it before in an MVC proj. I just can't remember since I didn't comment-out the command in the action I used.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll look forward to seeing the answer then.

Comment: Updated with answer. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Doh! I missed the asp.net tag. I was thinking WinForms. Thanks for sharing your answer.